# Function Quest: Bonferroni confidence and Interval estimates

Tags: r, bonferroni

Good day from Noob central!

I am looking for a prediction function that also gives me the Bonferroni confidence and interval estimates.  Something like:

```
predict(PH,data.frame(Time=20), interval = "confidence",adjust=bonferroni, level=.95)
```

Where PH is a linear regression (lm) and the output would be similar to

```
> fit       lwr         upr
> 209.2875  206.727     211.847
```

I have been googling the hell out of this question, which seems simple to me, with no good answers.

and it stems from a linear stats course questions as follows, "Calculate the desired confidence intervals using the Bonferroni procedure in a 90% family"

Help!

Comment: Sorry, a linear regression model.

Comment: I think you are confused, p-value adjustment - because of multiple comparisons - such as Bonferroni - is done on the p-values, not on the confidence interval. Is that what you are seeking?

Comment: So, this is for a homework question and it says "Calculate the desired confidence intervals using the Bonferroni procedure in a 90% family"

Comment: That is a weird formulation but I still think that the Bonferroni correction is in relation to the p-values, no the CI.